# Copy Constructor Issue C++: "0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000."

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, copy-constructor, biginteger

I'm having some trouble getting my copy constructor to work in my `BigInt` class I'm working on.

In `BigIntVector.cpp` in the copy constructor, the lines:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++) {
        vectorArray[i] = orig.vectorArray[i];
    }
```

causes the exception `0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.` Any help figuring out why would be appreciated. Thank you.

In `BigInt.cpp`:

```
// copy constructor
BigInt::BigInt(BigInt const& orig) 
 : isPositive(orig.isPositive)
, base(orig.base)
, skip(orig.skip) 
{
    this->bigIntVector = new BigIntVector(*orig.bigIntVector);
}

// constructor where operand is a long
BigInt::BigInt(long num) {
    base = 10;

    long sizeOfLong = 0; //holds size of num
    long tempNum = num;

    //get size of num
    if (tempNum == 0) {
        sizeOfLong = 1;
    }
    while (tempNum != 0)
    {
        tempNum /= 10;
        ++sizeOfLong;
    }

    //resize vector to match size of long
    this->bigIntVector = new BigIntVector(sizeOfLong);

    //cout << "sizeVec: " << bigIntVector.getSize() << endl;

    if (num < 0) {
        isPositive = false;
        num *= -1;
    }
    else {
        isPositive = true;
    }
    long pushedNum;
    //cout << "num: " << num << endl;
    for (int i = sizeOfLong - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        pushedNum = (long)(num%base);
        bigIntVector->setElementAt(i, pushedNum);
        num /= base;
    }
}

// destructor
BigInt::~BigInt() {
    delete[] this->bigIntVector;
}

// binary addition
BigInt BigInt::operator+(BigInt const& other) const {

    BigInt temp(*this);
    return temp += other;
}

//more code...
```

My `BigInt.h`:

```
class BigInt {
private:
    BigIntVector *bigIntVector;
    bool isPositive;
    int base;
    unsigned int skip;

public:
    BigInt(BigInt const& orig);
    BigInt(long num);
    ~BigInt();
    BigInt operator+(BigInt const& other) const;
    BigInt operator+() const;
    BigInt operator++();
    BigInt operator++(int dummy);
    BigInt operator+=(BigInt const& other);
    BigInt BigInt::operator-(BigInt const& other) const;
    BigInt BigInt::operator-=(BigInt const& other);
    bool operator==(BigInt const& other) const;
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream& os, BigInt& num);
};
inline BigInt operator+(long num, BigInt const& val) {
    return val + num;
}
inline bool operator==(long num, BigInt const& val) {
    return val == num;
}
```

My `BigIntVector` is a custom `Vector` class. Compared to STL Vector.

The constructors in `BigIntVector.cpp`:

```
// copy constructor
BigIntVector::BigIntVector(BigIntVector const& orig)
    : vectorSize(orig.vectorSize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++) {
        vectorArray[i] = orig.vectorArray[i];
    }
}

BigIntVector::~BigIntVector() {
    delete[] vectorArray;
}

//default constructor
BigIntVector::BigIntVector()
{
    vectorSize = 1;

    //vectorArray = (long *)malloc(10 * sizeof(long));
    vectorArray = new long[vectorSize];
    for (long i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++) {
        vectorArray[i] = 0;
    }
}

//constructor that initializes a custom size for vector
BigIntVector::BigIntVector(long initialSize)
{
    vectorSize = initialSize;

    //vectorArray = (long *)malloc(initialSize*sizeof(long));
    vectorArray = new long[vectorSize];
    for (long i = 0; i < initialSize; i++) {
        vectorArray[i] = 0;
    }
}

//more code
```

`main.cpp`:

```
int main(void) {

    // object with explicit constructor from long
    BigInt num1(12);

    cout << "num1 (12): " << num1 << endl;

    // object with implicit constructor from long
    BigInt num2 = 19;

    cout << "num2 (19): " << num2 << endl;

    // binary addition BigInt+BigInt
    BigInt num3 = num1 + num2;

    cout << "num3 (31): " << num3 << endl;

    BigInt numA = 99999;

    cout << "numA (99999): " << numA << endl;

    BigInt numB = 99999;

    cout << "numB (99999): " << numB << endl;

    BigInt numC = numA + numB;

    cout << "numC (199998): " << numC << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: you are passing reference to orig. you should use 'orig.bigIntVector'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing reference to orig. you should use 'orig.bigIntVector'

```
BigInt::BigInt(BigInt const& orig) 
 : isPositive(orig.isPositive)
, base(orig.base)
, skip(orig.skip) 
{
    this->bigIntVector = new BigIntVector(*(orig.bigIntVector));
}

should use *(orig.bigIntVector)
```

Comment: this->bigIntVector = new BigIntVector*(orig.bigIntVector); returns an error because they cannot be assigned to eachother.

Comment: this->bigIntVector = new BigIntVector(*(orig.bigIntVector)); Invokes BigIntVector's copy constructor

Comment: oh okay that works. However, I now see the memory error (same message listed above) is in the copy constructor for BigIntVector in the for loop.

I updated the OP with the new error location.

Comment: which line? are u able to step through?

Comment: in the for loop in the copy constructor for BigIntVector, it returns the error at vectorArray[i] = orig.vectorArray[i];

Comment: are you creating object pointed to by: 'orig' in that constructor? copy+paste the main.cpp code

Comment: I think the problem was vectorArray was initialized so it was spitting out errors

Comment: even though your original question was different and my answer worked, you changed the question again.. if you have the program working please accept my answer

Comment: sorry about not accepting, you have been very helpful! I updated BigInt.cpp with my + operator overloading function where it is having problems reading the memory at the 'return temp += other;' 

If you could help me with that it would be appreciated.

Comment: '+' operator overloading implementation is incorrect. you are  not providing real implementation of '+' operator on BigInt objects.