# Operator overloading implementation: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

When `return BigInt(*this) += other;` is executed in my BigInt implementation the error `0xC0000005: Access violation reading location (insert memory location here)` is spit out and the program closes. Any help with why it is doing this? For previous context to my program go to [Copy Constructor Issue C++: "0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577650/copy-constructor-issue-c-0xc0000005-access-violation-writing-location-0x000)

BigInt.cpp

```
// binary addition
BigInt BigInt::operator+(BigInt const& other) const {

    return BigInt(*this) += other;

}

// compound addition-assignment operator
BigInt BigInt::operator+=(BigInt const& other) {
    //return this->data = this->data + other.data;

    //BigInt thisBigInt = *this;

    if (!other.isPositive) {
        //return thisBigInt -= other;
    }
    //possible check for both negative???


    int sum = 0; //holds the sum of the value in both vectors
    int maxSize = 0; //holds size of biggest BigInt
    int carry = 0; //holds carry over value
    int sizeDifference = 0; //holds size difference between b and a if b is bigger

    //check size
    while (bigIntVector->getSize() < other.bigIntVector->getSize()) {
        bigIntVector->resize(); //increase size of first big int until it matches size of second
    }

    if (bigIntVector->getSize() > other.bigIntVector->getSize()) {
        sizeDifference = bigIntVector->getSize() - other.bigIntVector->getSize();
        //cout << "sizeDiff: " << sizeDifference << endl;
    }

    maxSize = bigIntVector->getSize();

    int otherCounter = other.bigIntVector->getSize() - 1; //keeps track if we are done getting digits from other array
    //cout << "otherCounter: " << otherCounter << endl;

    for (int i = maxSize - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        //cout << "element1: " << bigIntVector.getElementAt(i) << endl;
        //cout << "element2: " << other.bigIntVector.getElementAt(i) << endl;
        sum += bigIntVector->getElementAt(i);
        if (otherCounter >= 0) {
            sum += other.bigIntVector->getElementAt(i - sizeDifference); //move index if size is different
            sum += carry;
            carry = 0;
            //cout << "sum: " << sum << endl;
            if (sum > 9) {
                ++carry;
                bigIntVector->setElementAt(i, sum%base);
            }
            else {
                carry = 0;
                bigIntVector->setElementAt(i, sum%base);
            }

            --otherCounter; //only decrement otherCounter if we have reached 2nd vector elements
        }
        if (otherCounter < 0 && carry > 0) {
            bigIntVector->resize(); //increase size of big int
            bigIntVector->setElementAt(i, carry); //set carry in front of sum spot
        }
        sum = 0;
    }

    return *this;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `BigInt` by value from `operator+=`, this creates a copy and probably you haven't specified a correct copy constructor which takes care or internal dynamically allocated memory, you should return a reference:

```
BigInt& BigInt::operator+=(BigInt const& other)
```

Comment: what would my return for += be? would it still be 'return *this;' because leaving the same return still has the error popping up.

Comment: It should be returning a reference to the current object (`this`).  If you still have a bug, that means there is further debugging for you to do.

Comment: Return type is correct, then this means you are doing something wrong in the implementation.

Comment: what could I be doing in += that would cause the error listed above to be thrown?

Comment: also, do I need to change how I call += in the + overloading function?

Comment: @jankyCoder You are doing a lot of things in that function we have no idea about -- for example `bigIntVector->resize();`  So asking what you're doing wrong in that function isn't going to help unless you posted the entire class.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't involve anything happening in +=. All I know is that the memory location it can't read is 'this' itself. almost like it never got anything put in it.

Comment: ah, it seems the destructor in BigIntVector was erasing the array in it. but now it is in an infinitely calling 'return BigInt(*this) += other;'

Comment: @jankyCoder *it seems the destructor in BigIntVector was erasing the array in it* -- Isn't that what the destructor supposed to do?  Did you unit test your classes to ensure that the copying, assignment, and destructor work flawlessly?  It looks like there are basic issues with these operations.  Tests like `{BigInt x; BigInt y = x; BigInt z; z = x;}`  and tests similar to this is all you need to test all of your copying, assignment, and destruction.